# React testing mock implementation one, work with mocked funcitons

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am implementing a mock function for firebase authentication, I have mocked the firebase module like this:

```js
jest.mock("../../lib/api/firebase", () => {
  return {
    auth: {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
          user: {
            uid: "fakeuid",
          },
        };
      }),
      signOut: jest.fn(),
    },
    firestore: {
      collection: jest.fn(() => ({
        doc: jest.fn(() => ({
          collection: jest.fn(() => ({
            add: jest.fn(),
          })),
          set: jest.fn(),
        })),
      })),
    },
  };
});
```

right now *createUserWithEmailAndPassword* returns an user uid to fake the firebase response on signup. I use it in my test like this:

```js
.
.
.
 await wait(() => {
      expect(auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/dashboard");
      expect(getByText("You succesfully signed up!")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

it works perfectly fine, but how if I want the returned value to be something different for one test?
I saw there is mockImplementationOnce that seems to be the right path but I am struggling implementing it, any help?
Thanks,
F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mockReturnValueOnce` like this:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
.mockReturnValueOnce(/* your desired return value here */)
```

Just make sure you are mocking the return value *before* calling `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` in your test.

For example:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
.mockReturnValueOnce({user: { uid: 'mocked uid'}})

auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()

// Insert your expect statement(s) here
...
```

Comment: yes I came up with it too, I just have some warnings from typescript